# Jetpack compose : Problem while swiping pages in pager compasable

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, pager

I'm building a registration page with jetpack compose and I have implemented it in a horizontal pager linked with TabRow to display signup and login page respectively

but when I swipe to the other page (login or signup), the next page will build only after the swipe offset exceeds apporximately 50% of the screen width, and the pervious page will be rendered in the other page as shown in the video below

```
  @OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
  @Composable
  fun RegistrationHorizontalPageView() {
  val tabRowState = viewModel<TabRowViewModel>()


     HorizontalPager(
     count = 2,
     state = tabRowState.pagerState,
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
 ) {


    if(currentPage == 0){
        RegistrationPage()
    }else{
        LoginPage()
    }

  }
}
```

how to fix this ?[image: demo for the problem]

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: it was just a bug with the library itself, after it was updated, the problem gone,
so if you are using the most recent version of library then you should have no problem like this

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a list of tab Items that contain different elements of view.
Make sure to not use if else statements based on the page state because it is changing only after 50%, rather try to create your view always available.

For example you can do something like this:

```
sealed class TabItem(var title: String, var color: Color, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    object Registration : TabItem("REGISTRATION", Color.Red, { /* you can add here your composable*/} )
    object Login : TabItem("LOGIN", Color.Blue, { /* you can add here your composable*/} )
}
```

Usage:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val tabs = listOf(TabItem.Registration, TabItem.Login)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            indicator = { positions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, positions)
                )
            }
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
                val isSelected = pagerState.currentPage == index
                Tab(
                    selected = isSelected,
                    text = {
                        Text(text = tab.title)
                    },
                    onClick = {}
                )
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(
            count = tabs.size, 
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(tabs[page].color) // for the example, showing that both pages are rendered
            ){
                Text( modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), text = tabs[page].title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace `currentPage` by `page`

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun RegistrationHorizontalPageView() {
  val tabRowState = viewModel<TabRowViewModel>()


  HorizontalPager(
     count = 2,
     state = tabRowState.pagerState,
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
 ) { page -> 


    if(page == 0){
        RegistrationPage()
    } else {
        LoginPage()
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).